# Counting groups of letters, numbers, symbols in a string, and conditionally replace symbols

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, strings

I have a C++ programming task: read a string of characters and identify groups of letters, numbers and symbols. If in the given string there are more groups of letters than groups of symbols, replace all groups of symbols with "123":

Groups are subarrays each containing one particular type of symbol.

> #### Example input
>
> ```
> asd;=-0pa82)(*ui1oo
> ```
>
> #### Corresponding output
>
> ```
> asd1230pa82123ui1oo
> ```

Additionally it would be useful to print out additional info for that string:

```
Groups of letters: 4: asd pa ui oo 
Groups of symbols: 2: ;=- )(* 
Groups of numbers: 3: 0 82 1 

There are more groups of letters than groups of symbols in this line
```

---

My code for that problem is below. Can you recommend better/shorter solution? Or any suggestions to improve the code as well as feedback will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void CharsCount(string& str){
    vector<string> letters, symbols, numbers;
    string temp = "";
    static const string symbols_list = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?[]^_{|}~`\\";
    auto pos = string::npos;
    for (const auto& x: str){
        if ( isdigit(x) ) { // this char is digit
            if (temp.empty()){
                temp += x;
            } else if (isdigit(temp.back())){    //last char in temporary string - digit?
                temp += x;  //add that digit to the temp string
                } else if (isalpha(temp.back())){ //last char - digit?
                    letters.push_back(temp);    //save temp string in a digit vector
                    temp = "";
                    temp += x;
                } else {        //last digit is a symbol?
                    symbols.push_back(temp); //save temp to the symbols vector
                    temp = "";
                    temp += x;
                }
        }
        if (isalpha(x)) { 
            if (temp.empty()){
                temp += x;
            } else if (isalpha(temp.back())){    
                temp += x;  
            } else if (isdigit(temp.back())){
                numbers.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
                temp += x;
            } else {      
                symbols.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
                temp += x;
            }
        }
        if ((pos = symbols_list.find(x)) != string::npos ){//char - symbol?
            if (temp.empty()){
                temp += x;
            } else if (isalpha(temp.back())){    
                letters.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
                temp += x; 
            } else if (isdigit(temp.back())){
                numbers.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
                temp += x;
            } else {     
                temp += x;
            }
        }
        }

     //Adding temp to the associated vector after the main loop
        if (!temp.empty()){
            if (isalpha(temp.back())){
                letters.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
            } else if (isdigit(temp.back())){
                numbers.push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
            } else symbols.push_back(temp);
        }
   
    cout << "Groups of letters: " << letters.size() << ": ";
    for (auto x: letters){
        cout << x << " ";
    };
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Groups of symbols: " << symbols.size() << ": ";
    for (auto x: symbols){
        cout << x << " ";
    };
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Groups of numbers: " << numbers.size() << ": ";
    for (auto x: numbers){
        cout << x << " ";
    };
    cout << endl;
    //replacing the symbols if needed:
    if (letters.size() > symbols.size()){
        cout << "There are more groups of letters than groups of symbols in this line" << endl;
        cout << "Initial string: " << str << endl;
        for (auto z : symbols){
            str.replace(str.find(z), z.size(), "123");
        }
        cout << "Resulting string: " << str << endl;
    }
    }

int main() {
    string i = "asd;=-0pa82)(*ui1oo";
    CharsCount(i);        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a programming challenge. What's the source of the challenge? Do you have a link?

Comment: This is actually a programming task at my university's C++ class, not some competition or challenge.

Comment: Alright. Is the task as written in your question complete? Are there specific things they want you to consider for that chapter?

Comment: No, this task closes the part of the course regarding operations on strings/text. There are also some clarifications of what constitutes a group of letters, numbers, symbols, but I think it's pretty obvious from my example and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Headers and namespaces

We're missing `<cctype>` (for `std::isalpha()` and family).

Bringing all names in from a namespace is problematic; `namespace std` particularly so.  It [can silently change the meaning of your program](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

## Function interface

Avoid requiring a reference to a (mutable) value.  Prefer to accept a reference to a const string `(const std::string& str)`.  Since we want a value we can modify, we should accept a string *by value*:

```
void CharsCount(std::string str) {
```

That change allows us to call it more conveniently from `main()`, without needing to create a named variable:

```
CharsCount("asd;=-0pa82)(*ui1oo");
```

## We don't need `symbols_list`

As we're operating in the default ("C") locale, we can use `std::ispunct` to test for the symbols in our list:

```
    if (std::ispunct(x)) {
```

## Structure

At the moment, it's pretty much one big function that reads the input string and writes to `std::cout`.  It may well be worth splitting this into two functions, like this:

```
struct groups_result {
    std::vector<std::string> letters, symbols, numbers;
    std::string final_string;
};

groups_result process_string(const std::string& str);
void print_result(const groups_result& groups);
```

Although this seems like more work, it can allow us to write self-checking tests by comparing `groups_result` objects.  We can also choose where to print the output if we write

```
void print_result(std::ostream& os, const groups_result& groups);
```

## Repetition of code

Our main loop now has three blocks that all follow a common pattern:

- if `temp` is empty, add to it unconditionally
- if the current character is the same type as the previous, append it to `temp`
- otherwise, append `temp` to the appropriate vector and start a new string

We can avoid all the references to `temp.back()` by remembering the last-seen character (as a plain `char`).  We can do even better - we just need to know which function to use for the "is same class" test, and which vector we would append the result to.

This might be a bit harder to follow, because we're now introducing some indirection (the pointers `same_class` and `current_vector`), but it does reduce the repetition and make it easier to add new character types:

```
groups_result process_string(const std::string& str)
{
    groups_result groups{str, str};
    std::string temp = "";

    int (*same_class)(int) = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::string> *current_vector = nullptr;

    for (const auto& x: str) {
        const unsigned char ux = x;   // we need this for <cctype> functions
        // is x in the same group as previous character?
        if (!same_class || !same_class(ux)) {
            if (current_vector) {
                current_vector->emplace_back(std::move(temp));
            }
            // what's the new class?
            if (std::isalpha(ux)) {
                same_class = std::isalpha;
                current_vector = &groups.letters;
            } else if (std::isdigit(ux)) {
                same_class = std::isdigit;
                current_vector = &groups.numbers;
            } else if (std::ispunct(ux)) {
                same_class = std::ispunct;
                current_vector = &groups.symbols;
            } else {
                // ignored characters
                same_class = nullptr;
                current_vector = nullptr;
            }
            // start a new group
            temp.clear();
        }
        temp.push_back(x);
    }

    // Add last group to its vector
    if (current_vector && !temp.empty()) {
        current_vector->emplace_back(std::move(temp));
    }

    // Replace the symbols if needed
    if (groups.letters.size() > groups.symbols.size()) {
        for (auto z: groups.symbols) {
            groups.final_string.replace(str.find(z), z.size(), "123");
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

If we had many classes, we could get even more heavyweight by using an array of pairs (of "same class" function and vector-pointer) to replace the `if/else` chain there, but for just three functions it's probably not worth it:

```
    const std::pair<int(*)(int),std::vector<std::string>*> classes[] = {
        { std::isalpha, &groups.letters },
        { std::isdigit, &groups.numbers },
        { std::ispunct, &groups.symbols },
        { nullptr, nullptr }
    };

    for (const auto& x: str) {
        const unsigned char ux = x;   // we need this for <cctype> functions
        // is x in the same group as previous character?
        if (!same_class || !same_class(ux)) {
            if (current_vector) {
                current_vector->emplace_back(std::move(temp));
            }
            // what's the new class?
            for (auto char_class: classes) {
                if (!(same_class = char_class.first) || same_class(ux)) {
                    current_vector = char_class.second;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // start a new group
            temp.clear();
        }
        temp.push_back(x);
    }
```

## Repetition in the printing

We can make a useful function to simplify the printing:

```
static void print_group(std::ostream& os, const char *name, const std::vector<std::string>& values)
{
    os << "Groups of " << name << ": " << values.size() << ":";
    for (auto const& x: values) {
        os << " " << x;
    }
    os << '\n';
}

void print_result(std::ostream& os, const groups_result& groups)
{
    print_group(os, "letters", groups.letters);
    print_group(os, "symbols", groups.symbols);
    print_group(os, "numbers", groups.numbers);

    if (groups.letters.size() > groups.symbols.size()) {
        os << "There are more groups of letters than groups of symbols in this line" << '\n';
        os << "Initial string: " << groups.initial_string << '\n';
        os << "Resulting string: " << groups.final_string << '\n';
    }
}
```

I've also used `'\n'` rather than `std::endl` to end a line, as we don't need to flush the output until the program finishes.

## Make the test program more flexible

Instead of having to recompile every time we change the input, let's provide strings as command-line arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        print_result(std::cout, process_string(argv[i]));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This time I did use `std::endl`, so we get output as each string is processed.

---

## Putting it all together

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct groups_result {
    std::string initial_string = {}, final_string = {};
    std::vector<std::string> letters = {}, symbols = {}, numbers = {};
};

groups_result process_string(const std::string& str)
{
    groups_result groups{str, str};
    std::string temp = "";

    int (*same_class)(int) = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::string> *current_vector = nullptr;

    const std::pair<int(*)(int),std::vector<std::string>*> classes[] = {
        { std::isalpha, &groups.letters },
        { std::isdigit, &groups.numbers },
        { std::ispunct, &groups.symbols },
        { nullptr, nullptr }
    };

    for (const auto& x: str) {
        const unsigned char ux = x;   // we need this for <cctype> functions
        // is x in the same group as previous character?
        if (!same_class || !same_class(ux)) {
            if (current_vector) {
                current_vector->emplace_back(std::move(temp));
            }
            // what's the new class?
            for (auto char_class: classes) {
                if (!(same_class = char_class.first) || same_class(ux)) {
                    current_vector = char_class.second;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // start a new group
            temp.clear();
        }
        temp.push_back(x);
    }

    // Add last group to its vector
    if (current_vector && !temp.empty()) {
        current_vector->emplace_back(std::move(temp));
    }

    // Replace the symbols if needed
    if (groups.letters.size() > groups.symbols.size()) {
        for (auto z: groups.symbols) {
            groups.final_string.replace(str.find(z), z.size(), "123");
        }
    }

    return groups;
}


static void print_group(std::ostream& os, const char *name, const std::vector<std::string>& values)
{
    os << "Groups of " << name << ": " << values.size() << ":";
    for (auto const& x: values) {
        os << " " << x;
    }
    os << '\n';
}

void print_result(std::ostream& os, const groups_result& groups)
{
    print_group(os, "letters", groups.letters);
    print_group(os, "symbols", groups.symbols);
    print_group(os, "numbers", groups.numbers);

    if (groups.letters.size() > groups.symbols.size()) {
        os << "There are more groups of letters than groups of symbols in this line" << '\n';
        os << "Initial string: " << groups.initial_string << '\n';
        os << "Resulting string: " << groups.final_string << '\n';
    }
}

// Test program
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        print_result(std::cout, process_string(argv[i]));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code can be made more readable and several computations can be carried out parallelly to improve running time.
 
For example: `str.replace()` can be avoided, the other string can be formed alongside counting groups which will greatly improve performance.

Steps to approach such problems:
1. Draw Deterministic finite automata (DFA).
2. Convert DFA to code.

Here is my implementation,

```
void process(string str){

int i = 0;
string otherStr = "";                // symbol groups replaced by "123"

int alphaCount = 0;                  // total alpha group 
string alphaStr = "";                // all alpha groups seperated by space

int digitCount = 0;                  // total digit groups
string digitStr = "";                // digit groups separated by space

int symbolCount = 0;                  // total symbol group
string symbolStr = "";                // symbol group separeted by space

while(i < str.size()){

   if(isalpha(str[i])){
      for(; i<str.size() && isalpha(str[i]); i++){ 
          otherStr += str[i];
         alphaStr += str[i];
      }

      alphaCount++;
      alphaStr += " ";
      if(i<str.size())
         --i;
   }
   else if(isdigit(str[i])){
      for(; i<str.size() && isdigit(str[i]); i++){
         otherStr += str[i];
         digitStr += str[i];
      }

      digitCount++;
      digitStr += " ";
      if(i<str.size())
         --i;
   }
   else if(isSymbol(str[i])){         //isSymbol() -> implement it.
      otherStr += "123"
      for(; i<str.size() && isSymbol(str[i]); i++){   
         symbolStr += str[i];
      } 

      symbolCount++;
      symbolStr += " ";
      if(i<str.size())
         --i;
   }
   else
      i++;
}


/********************results**************************/

                     // Here

/*****************************************************/

}
```

Running time: \$O(n)\$

Answer (score 1):

Ok I will list a few things:

**String Default Constructor**

```
string temp = "";
```

The `= ""` is pretty redundant, considering that's what the default constructor of `string` does. Also, there is an associated function [`std::string::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) for clearing a string.

---

**Vertical Spacing**

Looking over your function, all of the code seems compacted, with no vertical spacing. Consider adding newlines between variable declarations and logic, so your code is more readable

---

**Extra Spaces**

```
if ( isdigit(x) )
```

I see you use spaces inside the parentheses here, but not in your other conditionals. Be consistent!

---

**Indentation**

```
    if (temp.empty()){
            temp += x;
    } else if (isdigit(temp.back())){    //last char in temporary string - digit?
            temp += x;  //add that digit to the temp string
            } else if (isalpha(temp.back())){ //last char - digit?
                    letters.push_back(temp);    //save temp string in a digit vector
                    temp = "";
                    temp += x;
            } else {        //last digit is a symbol?
                    symbols.push_back(temp); //save temp to the symbols vector
                    temp = "";
                    temp += x;
            }
```

In this part of the code, the bottom two conditional clauses look like they are part of a nested if statement. You should be consistent with indentation, not just in this part of the code (Your function indentation is horrible sometimes). Additionally, your comments for the last `else if` are inconsistent with your actual code.

---

**Size vs Length of a string**

```
z.size()
```

This is just me being pedantic, but for strings, you are taking its *length*, not its *size*. Maybe use `std::string::length`!